# grails 2.0 <g:javascript> doesn't work

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have created a new grails project and run it, but I can't see the

`< g:javascript library="application" />`

anywhere in the source, it's like it doesn't get called at all, I'm not sure if this is a bug or not?

Comment: You probably won't have much luck asking questions about weird behavior in Grails 2.0 since it's still in development. You'd be much better off asking on the User mailing list. They would quickly tell you why this doesn't work and what the workaround is.

Comment: @Burt Oh ye of little faith :)

Comment: I tried the mailing list already, but my post is still pending for ages.

Comment: @toy - you may need to subscribe to the mailing list before your posts are accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
<g:javascript library="application" />
```

with:

```
<g:javascript library="application" />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

This is a [breaking change](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7801) introduced by the new resources plugin